# StackExchange Query Help t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Would anybody be able to help me with this exercise. I am used to querying on postgresql and not t-sql and I am running into trouble with how some of my data aggregates

My assignment requires me to:

- Create a query that returns the number of comments made on each day for each post from the top 50 most commented on posts in the past year.

For example, this query below is giving me a non aggregated result set:

```
select cast(creationdate as date),
        postid,
        count(id)
from comments 
where  postid = 17654496
group by creationdate, postid
```

The schema is all here

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/898297

Comment: but i need to group by date by post id

Comment: Why do you need a group by postid when it is a where condition?

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, i only added the where clause to share a small example of it now aggregating it correctly. The assignment requires me to create a query that returns the numbes of comments made on each day for each post from the top 50 most commented on posts in the past year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `CTE` get the `count` by date.

then use window function with `ROW_NUMBER` make row number `order by` count amount desc.

```
;with CTE as (
  select  cast(creationdate as date) dt,
          postid,
          count(id) cnt
  from comments 
  WHERE creationdate between dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) and getdate()  
  group by cast(creationdate as date), postid
  ), CTE2 AS (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by cnt desc) rn
    from CTE
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE2 
  WHERE rn <=50
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/898322/test